# Should I accept the solution to my problem or the most generic solution to the same problem?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

I have a question that has a few answers: [Fix wkhtmltopdf headers clipping content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447672/)

My own answer that I accepted was the one that solved the issue for me eventually, but a few years later another user added an answer that solves the same problem with a different source. This new answer, I think, solves a more popular problem that people have (especially now, things have changed).

The answers are definitely different in their approach to the situation, so I'm not choosing between two similar simultaneous answers. Should I change my accepted answer to the more useful generic answer or should I keep mine where I explained how I solved my issue?

Comment: The check mark is meant to indicate whichever answer most helped the person who asked the question, not the answer that's most popular with the community (that's what votes are for).  If that's still your own answer you don't have to change it.

Comment: So effectively this newer answer does not actually answer the question asked and belongs on a different question...

Comment: @BSMP why add this as a comment and not an answer?

Comment: The “populist” badge is for an answer that outvotes an accepted answer.  Switching the accepted answer to this newer answer would deny the answerer the chance of getting that badge.  This isn’t a reason to not switch the accepted answer, but pointing out that answers better than the accepted answer are expected to show up from time to time.

Comment: Let the Tooltip be your guide: Accept Mark = "*Click to accept this answer because it solved **your** problem or was the most helpful in finding **your** solution*" versus Up/Down-vote = "*This answer is (not) useful*".  Your - *belonging to or associated with the person or people that the speaker is addressing* - I.E. the question asker.

Comment: This is why when I'm looking for a solution before posting my own question, the highest upvoted answers take precedence over the accepted answer in the fight for my initial attention.  Upvotes tend to indicate general acceptance.

Comment: After getting my problem solved, I'd think of other people searching for the same problem and the answer that's best for them. New answers on old answered questions don't get voted-up much. I don't think of SO as a way to solve MY problem only, but also a way to share the knowledge that can save hours or even days for others. TL;DR, choose the most helpful to THE problem (as worded in the question) not YOUR problem (that may have other unknown factors leding you to decide on a specific answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two possibilities here:

**1. The new answer now solves your original issue in a better way (possibly this way wasn't possible when you first answered the question, or just wasn't though of).**

In this case I would change the accepted answer to the new answer. For reference, this is what I have done on my question [Mime type for WOFF fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594823/mime-type-for-woff-fonts). The best solution has changed over time as Chrome has updated, and I've changed the accepted answer to match what is now the best thing to do.

**2. The new answer doesn't solve your original issue, but solves a different issue that has similar symptoms (and thus people find your question looking for it).**

In this case I would leave the accepted answer as the one which fixed your original issue. However, I would also edit either that answer or your question and link to the answer which solves the other issue. Ideally you would also add a short paragraph explaining the different circumstances in which these symptoms occur, and which actions are appropriate in each case.

**The golden rule (in my mind):**

The 'Accepted Check Mark' represents the answer that the asker of the question considers the best answer to the question.

Comment: 1. It's not appropriate to include commentary on the answers in the question.  The question is where you ask the question, not respond to answers. 2. You shouldn't be editing in commentary of other answers into someone else's answer.  Again, an answer is where you answer the question, not commentate on other people's answers.  3. Answers need to *answer the question*.  Posting an answer that doesn't even answer the question is *not a good answer*.  If it's useful information for some other question/problem, then *it should be posted as an answer to that other question*.

Comment: got to agree with @Servy here, an answer shouldnt exist to promote an answer on the same thread

Comment: I would emphasis the last words :  *the asker of the question considers the best answer to **his** question.*

Comment: @Servy, my intention was that the author edit *their own answer* which does answer the question in it's own right to also acknowledge the existence of the other answer which wasn't as helpful for them, but may be more helpful to others. In the case that the answer is someone else's perhaps a comment could be used instead.

I agree that from a purism point of view it doesn't make sense to include commentary in the question, but I have seen it used to very good effect before, and at the end of the day the purpose of the site is to be useful.

Comment: @NicoBurns And the site is more useful when reading the question actually tells you what the question is, rather than giving you commentary on the answers, which, if you actually wanted to read, you'd see by looking at the answers and their comments.  LIkewise, when reading an answer, you'd want to see what their answer to the question is, not their commentary on another answer; if you wanted to see that user's commentary on another answer, you'd go look at the comments of that answer.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that, unless a better solution for the **asked question** is provided, the accepted answer should not change.

In general the accepted answer means to show which answer helped the asker most in solving the problem actually outlined in the question.
Some answers might provide a more versatile solution or tackle more problems, but it ultimately is not the goal to measure general usefulness of an answer by acceptance, but the usefulness for the problem described in the question.

New answers, which provide useful information for solving e.g. more popular problems (as said in the question) should perhaps be upvoted, to indicate usefulness.